# The C compiler "clang.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to compile shell script that compiles the C project library, but i am stuck at this when it comes to compile the nmake part.

I am using NDK 21 and cmake version is 3.10

I am using shell script using bash same as defined here, i want to compress this library as they showing in the docs running ./android.sh

Please check the link: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg#52-build-scripts

here is the attached log:

```
DEBUG: Downloading library source: cpu-features

DEBUG: Checking if cpu-features is already downloaded at /d/Bilals/Projects/GithubProjects/mobile-ffmpeg/src/cpu-features

INFO: cpu-features library already downloaded

INFO: cpu-features already downloaded. Source folder found at /d/Bilals/Projects/GithubProjects/mobile-ffmpeg/src/cpu-features

-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Bilals/PcBackupData/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_adf3f\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Bilals/PcBackupData/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at D:/Bilals/PcBackupData/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "D:/Bilals/PcBackupData/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/Bilals/Projects/GithubProjects/mobile-ffmpeg/android/build/cpu-features/arm/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_adf3f\fast"
    The system cannot find the file specified
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_adf3f\fast"
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Bilals/Projects/GithubProjects/mobile-ffmpeg/android/build/cpu-features/arm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Bilals/Projects/GithubProjects/mobile-ffmpeg/android/build/cpu-features/arm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

and here is my environmental variables

[image]

Comment: Post the error log as text, not a screenshot of it. Anyway, how are you building? With Gradle, or with some custom solution? Add your build script to the question.

Comment: Looks like nmake is not on your path

Comment: @AlanBirtles there is no nmake in this path, only clang

path-> D:/Bilals/PcBackupData/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/

Comment: @Michael edited kindly check

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Linux Make`, not `NMake`. Generally speaking, these scripts were never tuned to run on Windows, in cygwin or mingw shell, even though I have run them in WSL (Ubuntu) bash.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i am using to compress that library [link](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) to get smaller size in my project as i have set all my environment for android studio in windows, so i just wanna achieve that on windows.

Comment: You can build mobile-ffmpeg in WSL. You don't even need WSL2, but you need NDK for Linux. You can integrate this build script with Android Studio using a custom gradle task.